# Maven Could not resolve dependencies for project, Could not find artifact com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, selenium, maven

**Problem description**

I'm working on a maven project which consists of 2 modules, pageobjects-users and webdriver-tests-users, I am new to java and I don't know how to fix this error: "Failed to execute goal on project pageobject-users: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.app:pageobject-users:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
"

this problem occurs when I use mvn package or mvn package install commandline, everything works fine on IntelliJ IDEA

catalog tree

```
 my-app
    ├── my-app.iml
    ├── pageobject-users
    │   ├── pageobject-users.iml
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── main
    │   │   │   ├── java
    │   │   │   │   ├── LandingPage.java
    │   │   │   │   └── RegistrationPage.java
    │   │   │   └── resources
    │   │   └── test
    │   │       └── java
    │   └── target
    │       ├── classes
    │       │   ├── LandingPage.class
    │       │   └── RegistrationPage.class
    │       └── generated-sources
    │           └── annotations
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   ├── main
    │   │   └── java
    │   │       └── com
    │   │           └── mycompany
    │   │               └── app
    │   │                   ├── App.java
    │   │                   └── TestRunner.java
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── com
    │               └── mycompany
    │                   └── app
    │                       └── AppTest.java
    ├── target
    │   ├── classes
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── mycompany
    │   │           └── app
    │   │               ├── App.class
    │   │               └── TestRunner.class
    │   └── test-classes
    │       └── com
    │           └── mycompany
    │               └── app
    │                   └── AppTest.class
    └── webdriver-tests-users
        ├── pom.xml
        ├── src
        │   ├── main
        │   │   ├── java
        │   │   └── resources
        │   └── test
        │       └── java
        │           ├── CheckIfAccountCanBeCreated.java
        │           ├── CheckIfCookiesCanBeAccepted.java
        │           ├── CheckIfGOVLoginButtonWorks.java
        │           ├── CheckIfRegistrationLinkWorks.java
        │           ├── CheckIfStandardLoginButtonWorks.java
        │           └── TestSuite.java
        ├── target
        │   ├── generated-test-sources
        │   │   └── test-annotations
        │   └── test-classes
        │       ├── CheckIfAccountCanBeCreated.class
        │       ├── CheckIfCookiesCanBeAccepted.class
        │       ├── CheckIfGOVLoginButtonWorks.class
        │       ├── CheckIfRegistrationLinkWorks.class
        │       ├── CheckIfStandardLoginButtonWorks.class
        │       └── TestSuite.class
        └── webdriver-tests-users.iml
```

my-app pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <modules>
    <module>pageobject-users</module>
    <module>webdriver-tests-users</module>
  </modules>

  <name>my-app</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
      <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>pageobjects-users</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdriver-tests-users</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

pageobject-users pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pageobject-users</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

webdriver-tests-users pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>webdriver-tests-users</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>pageobject-users</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Don't define a dependency on the parent POM.

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: One of the mistakes that you made is that you put `my-app` as dependency into the modules.

Comment: I've added dependencies on parent pom in modules cuz I want to have access to TestRunner class, w/o the dependency I cannot resolve the import

Comment: Never add a dependency on the parent. Add a dependency on the module you want to use.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you

Comment: If you have solved the issue, please write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

I got it solved by creating third module, after that I moved my TestRunner.class to the module and added dependency on it.